# Snaps with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, snap, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in order to learn snaps. I begin with "basic snap usage" from [tutorials.ubuntu.com](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com). I installed snapd successfuly, but as i search for "hello" snap, it says: error openning parameter file, where as in the tutorial a list of snaps includes the name hello were listed. Does Ubuntu 14.4 not supported snaps?

@N0rbert After installing snapd, the output of apt-cache policy snapd is:

```
snapd:
  Installiert:           2.34.2~14.04.1
  Installationskandidat: 2.34.2~14.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.34.2~14.04.1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy snapd` to the question. Do you have any output of `snap search hello-snap`?

Comment: [Snaps available on 14.04](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/03/30/snaps-are-now-available-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop-and-server). Problem solved? :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes! the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you try to run a snap on 14.04, you might experience the error “The command cannot be found”. This is due to the fact that “/snap/bin” has not been added to the $PATH environment variable. To do so, a script called “apps-bin-path.sh” has been added to /etc/profile.d. It will automatically run after you reboot or re-login and add snaps launchers to your path.

https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/03/30/snaps-are-now-available-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop-and-server